# C# regex help, how to match this patttern

Tags: regex

I have a string something like "[aaa][vad][adf]", i would like to use regex to capture the data in[], and chars in [] can be char and number and no length limit. I am regex noob, can anyone help me on this?
Thanks.

Comment: I recommend you look at the RegEx cheat sheet to get a basic idea (http://bit.ly/rQ7m9b). It is preferable that you can ask your question with expressions you've tried and haven't been able to make work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
var data = "[asd][dfhg][asfsa243]";

var re = new Regex(@"\[([^\]]*)\]");

var matches = re.Matches(data);

for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++ )
{
    var m = matches[i];
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

This outputs:

```
asd
dfhg
asfsa243
```

The regular expression `\[([^\]]*)\]` matches zero or more occurrences of a character that isn't the `]` character and which is between a pair of square brackets (`[` and `]`)

Answer (score 1):

This regex might work for you:

```
\[(\w+)\]
```

That if you by `char` refers to [`word character`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_%28computing%29#word_character)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion:

```
\[(\w+)\]
```

The charachter will be provided in the first group of the match, like this:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"\[([\w\d]*)\]");
MatchCollection matchCollection = regex.Matches(stringToTest);
foreach (Match match in matchCollection)
{
    Debug.Print(match.Groups[0].Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some good resources for building regex's
http://www.regexlib.com
http://regexpal.com/

Here is the regex for Alphanumeric:

```
 ^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

Here's how to ensure there are 3:

```
 /^([a-zA-Z0-9]){3}$/
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try -

```
[^\[\]\W]+

var matches = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches("[aaa][vad][adf]",@"[^\[\]\W]+").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value);
```

That should ignore any '[', ']' and non-word characters and would return 'aaa', 'vad' and 'adf' from your example string.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? Appears to work for me with example given.